# Question about affine open covering

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let

- $f: X\to Y$ be a quasi compact separated morphism
- $\{U_i\}$ be an open affine covering of $X$
- $V$ be an open affine subset of $Y$

In Hartshorne's AG book chapter III, proposition 8.7 uses ;

$\{U_i \cap f^{-1}(V)\}$ forms an open **affine** cover of $f^{-1}(V)$

Is it really true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true, but it is not what Hartshorne uses. You need $Y$ separated, then the cartesian square $$\begin{matrix} U_i\cap f^{-1}(V) & \to & U_i\times V \\\\ \downarrow && \downarrow \\\\ Y & \to & Y\times Y \end{matrix}$$ exhibits $U_i\cap f^{-1}(V)$ as a closed subscheme of the affine scheme $U_i\times V$. See also EGA I (Springer edition), 5.3.10.